# French equivalent for 'cheesy'

Tags: vocabulaire

Is there a French word or term which means the same as calling someone *[cheesy](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cheesy)*?

> (informal) too emotional or romantic, in a way that is embarrassing
>
> - a cheesy love song
> - a cheesy romance novel

Also, apologies if I'm off-topic completely.

Comment: I think the definition of cheesy you gave is wrong. To quote [urban dictionnary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheesy) : This is an important word and nobody has it right yet. What it means is: Trying too hard, unsubtle, and inauthentic.

Comment: The definition of _cheesy_ provided in the question is a valid one, it's just that there are also others. As in many cases, the most appropriate definition will depend on the context and the part of the world. I certainly wouldn't rely on the Urban Dictionary as an authoritative source.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- *[À l'eau de rose](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99eau_de_rose)* comes to mind. It works for a book, a song, a movie, a serial… but might occasionally be used for someone, e.g. *C'est une chanteuse à l'eau de rose*<sup>1</sup>.

Also

- [*Ringard*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ringard) implies outdated too.
- [*Mélo*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9lo)
- [*Mielleux*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Mielleux) and [*sirupeux*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/sirupeux), adjectives built from food (honey and syrup), just like "cheesy" is built from "cheese."

A formal and/or literary equivalent might be:

- [*Mièvre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mi%C3%A8vre)

On the opposite, an informal one is:

- [Cucul la praline](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3172/what-does-%C3%AAtre-cul-cul-mean)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Voir [cette page](https://unreal.fr/forums/reponse/ringards-kitchs-les-meilleurs-clips-33/) qui a la particularité de regrouper quatre des propositions faites dans les diverses réponses proposées: *ringard*, *kitch*, *à l'eau de rose* et *gnangnan*.</sub>

Comment: Yes, la seule réponse qui contient des mots qui sont réellement des mots du vocabulaire français.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Les autres réponses contiennent des mots et expressions qui font elles-aussi partie du vocabulaire français. La majorité des mots que l'on trouve dans les dictionnaires a commencé par ne pas y être…

Comment: Effectivement. Il faut croire que j'ai laissé mon désir politique de ne *pas* voir des mots familiers devenir la norme l'emporter sur la situation réelle.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Oui, le français s'est d'ailleurs construit sur le « latin familier ». D'autre part, il fallait bien sûr lire *…des mots et expressions qui font **eux-aussi** partie du vocabulaire français.*

Comment: Touché. Toutefois, je suis d'accord avec l'accord au féminin dans ce cas (il est grand temps que le masculin cesse de l'emporter), ça ne m'a donc pas dérangé :D

Comment: Je ne trouve pas "mièvre" particulièrement formel ni littéraire...

Comment: @Shautieh disons soutenu et un peu suranné. On ne rencontre plus guère *mièvre* que dans les livres.

Comment: I thought cheesy was built from the word _cheese_ meant to make people smile when pronouncing it (because of its long EE sound), a synonym in that sense to _seaweed_, not from the edible substance that only happen to be a common enough word with the right sonority to be elected for the purpose.

Comment: @Feelew Yes, didn't meant cheese and honey taste the same ;-) I found interesting the coincidence between the way these words are built so I pointed it out. French *mielleux* and *sirupeux* evoke sweetness, soft consistency and a  smooth way to flow. Melting cheese would share some of these characteristics but that's just another coincidence. I agree the "cheese" smile must be the root of "cheesy".

Comment: @jlliagre Mince, cela fait trente ans que je parle à des livres alors ^^

Comment: @Shautieh « ne ... (plus) guère que » ≠ « ne … que ». TLFi: **guère** *…implique une restriction moins forte que ne… que employé seul : il permet au locuteur de prendre en compte d'autres cas que celui auquel il se limite dans l'énoncé de la prop. contenant ne… que (ce qui permet, gén., de dire ou de laisser entendre que ces autres cas sont ou seront négligés dans la suite du discours).* Oui, « mièvre » s'emploie en effet  encore en français soutenu (→ *formal*).

Answer (score 9):

*Nunuche* and *cucul* are the best translations I can find. They keep the informal aspect and exactly mean "too emotional or romantic, in a way that is embarrassing" while:

- *kitsch* and *ringard* don't necessarily apply to romance or love
- *à l'eau de rose*, *mélo* and *mièvre* are not informal and the first one doesn't  apply to people but only books, movies, etc.

Comment: ... mais nunuche et cucul ne sont pas des mots.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Autant que *cheesy* à mon avis.

Comment: oh... heh, bon point. quoique je m'interroge, cheesy n'est-il pas un genre d'adjectif de ce qui est fromagé?

Comment: There's no point describing things as "not words" if they're attested and people use them regularly. :p "gnangnan", for example, is in Collins... The useful thing is to talk about them in terms of register, degree of colloquialness, recency, currency or whatever other characterisations they evoke. Particularly when a translation-y question like this is asked, it's helpful if the asker gives some idea of the context they need it for, so appropriate answers can be given...

Comment: As for the English "cheesy", I'd say the first meaning, involving literal cheese is okay even in formal contexts ("This quiche is rather cheesy"); the second meaning, exaggerated/contrived/sappy, will be widely understood but wouldn't be okay in formal contexts or perhaps understood by older generations. (OED has "cheesy" as "showy" from the mid-19th century, but "cheesy book", "movie", or "song" in ngrams appears at the end of the 80s and sharply rises in the 90s). How non-wordy are these informal words? :p

Comment: Well, if that's the accepted stance around here, sure! As you may have noticed, while I am a native speaker, I am new to this stack and just wondered if it was really on topic, on *French language*, to suggest using words that are actually familiar-level speaking. On the other hand, as the original cheesy is familiar, I guess familiar expressions are valid candidates for translation.

Comment: Précisément. :) Not that I represent the standard (less than 2 months myself), so just take it as my siding with the stance, but that seems like the ideal: accept and match the asker's input register unless the question really doesn't make sense.

Comment: If I may add "gnangnan" to the list :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cucul

Comment: Nunuche et cucul sont bien des mots, ce n'est pas le soucis, mais ce sont des mots de gamins, surtout le deuxième. Vous imaginez un homme d'une quarantaine d'année expliquer qu'il a besoin d'aller au popo pour faire pipi ? Bah c'est pareil...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi CNRTL semble ne pas prendre en compte l'existence du français hors de ses frontières? Aucune trace d'une expression québecoise (je vous invite à cherche "quétaine" par exemple). Cela ne devrait pas être considéré comme une référence s'ils ne considèrent pas les autres entités francophones.

Comment: @Shautieh Je ne vois aucun problème a dire que telle ou telle personne est « cucul la praline » et je n'en voyais déjà pas quand j'avais 40 ans. C'est une expression argotique utilisée en France par des adultes depuis au moins 75 ans (Marcel Aymé - Travelingue - 1941), par exemple [ici](http://www.berthomeau.com/2016/03/ce-petit-heritier-d-une-maison-de-champagne-est-vraiment-tres-cucul-la-praline-dixit-un-proprietaire-bordelais.html) par un propriétaire bordelais.

Comment: @jlliagre "cucul la praline" passe mieux je suis d'accord, mais dire de quelque chose ou quelqu'un que c'est/qu'il est cucul, pas tant...

Answer (score 7):

On pourrait peut-être employer un composé avec [*romantico-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/romantico-) en « double qualification, avec une nuance généralement péjorative » (TLFi), comme avec : « Lignes de divagations romantico-amoureuses, dans le dialogue du rendez-vous nocturne, aisément amputables. » (Gide, *Journal*, 1941). Je suis personnellement familier avec la composition, sans doute fort peu usitée, « romantico-mocheton » où le [moche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moche) est diminué ([-on](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-on)) de surcroît. On a aussi tout simplement un sens péjoratif ou ironique de *sentimental*, « [q]ui accorde une place exagérée au sentiment ou romanesque. *Feuilleton, genre, roman sentimental* » et on peut aussi avec ce mot avoir l'élément *sentimentalo-* en composition pour ajouter des nuances. Par substantivation on peut aussi employer la personne qui *donne dans le sentimental*, de même sens...

---

Au Québec, peut-être un peu différemment du sens présenté en question, on peut avoir recours au nom et à l'adjectif *quétaine* (att. 1970) qui correspond d'« assez près » au *ringard* en français de France, dans le sens de *vieillot* et *de mauvais goût* (DHLF/Rey). C'est péjoratif, familier et usuel. On en a des exemples au *Wiktionnaire* pour qualifier des personnes (mais le deuxième exemple révèle certaines des propriétés du *quétaine* ou d'être *quétaine* dans le contexte de la réalisation cinématographique) :

> « En fait, l’opéra nous donne la permission d'être quétaines! Les
>   chics connaisseurs de Bayreuth et de La Scala, l’engeance la plus snob
>   et la plus discriminatoire du monde, le savent-ils qu’ils sont de
>   véritables quétaines ? » (Michel Tremblay, [*La nuit des princes
>   charmants*, 1995](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=G5kkAQAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3ADgnMKcKYQbEC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22d%27%C3%AAtre%20qu%C3%A9taines%22))
>
> ---
>
> Pour pousser l’insulte à son comble, un torrent de clichés déferle sur
>   cette ânerie réalisée avec soin mais sans goût. C’est que Fuqua est ce
>   qu’on appelle communément chez nous « un moyen quétaine » [n.b. on lira *tout un*]. En
>   témoignent les nombreux ralentis sur le héros viril avançant vers la
>   caméra pendant qu’une explosion embrase l’arrière-plan, la photo aux
>   couleurs saturées pour communiquer un état de fièvre, le montage
>   frénétique pour indiquer un état d’urgence, une musique pompière pour
>   s’assurer qu’on est bien assommés. Tout cela ne serait qu’un moindre
>   mal si les dialogues n’étaient pas d’une niaiserie tellement profonde
>   qu’ils déclenchent l’hilarité. (Le Devoir, [*Un thriller à numéros
>   stérile et futile*](http://www.ledevoir.com/culture/cinema/136271/un-thriller-a-numeros-sterile-et-futile), 2007)
>
> [ Citations tirées du Wiktionnaire, à [quétaine](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qu%C3%A9taine). ]

Victory-Lévy Beaulieu semble utiliser la graphie [*kétaine*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C3%A9taine). Dans tous les cas on peut aussi facilement avoir *une chanson d'amour quétaine* ou *un roman d'amour bien quétaine* etc. Enfin [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/cheesy/569677) fait référence à *nul* dans le contexte du *cheesy excuse* probablement avec l'idée d'absence de valeur, qui rejoint sans doute l'idée d'[*inferior/cheap*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cheesy?s=t) pour l'inanimé.

Comment: Avez-vous plus détails sur l'étymologie du mot _quétaine_?

Comment: @Frank Le DHLF/Rey comporte trois éléments communs avec l'entrée au Wiktionnaire (lien quétaine sous les citations) : _quêter (demander l'aumône), quêteux (pauvre, misérable), Keaton (un nom de famille avec une histoire, peut-être)_. On ne sait pas exactement. Merci !

Comment: Je comprends mieux maintenant. L'origine _quêter_ me convient :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Cucu(l)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cucu) est avéré dans le dictionnaire [TLFi : Trésor de la langue Française informatisé](http://www.atilf.fr/tlfi), ATILF - CNRS & Université de Lorraine.

Voir également [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3173/13172).

Comment: Plusieurs expressions très courantes québecoises n'y figurent pas (cherchez quétaine par exemple). J'ignore comment cela peut-être considéré comme une référence.

Comment: Parce que le québecois, est, au mieux, un dialecte minoritaire, dont les Français se tapent pas mal...

Answer (score 2):

You can say [Kitsch](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/kitsch). As in *une chanson kitsch*; or *ce film était très kitsch*.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility could be gnangnan/gniangnian

Comment: Except they are not words, but rather familiar expressions.

Comment: granted but not everything can be translated word for word

Answer (score 1):

Il y a aussi l'expression « [fleur bleue](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fleur_bleue) » qui peut vouloir dire (peut-être péjorativement) : *Très sentimental ; naïvement romantique* (Wiktionnaire ; voir aussi [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bleu), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fleur/34112/locution?q=fleur%20bleue#172325)).

Answer (score 0):

Comme évoqué par l'un des commentaires, l'expression "être fleur bleue" peut s'approcher de la signification de "cheesy" en désignant le caractère sentimental – allant jusqu’à la naïveté – d’une personne en proie à un ardent romantisme. En effet, dans le langage des fleurs, le bleu pâle exprime la tendresse idéalisée, discrète et timide.

Comme "cheesy", « fleur bleue » est souvent utilisé de manière péjorative.

Cette expression est issue du courant romantique du XIXe siècle et apparaît d’abord en Allemagne, dans le roman inachevé du baron Friedrich von Hardenberg, connu sous le nom de Novalis, écrit en 1802.

Source : [La langue française](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/expressions-francaises/fleur-bleue-definition-et-origine/).